# rails render :json method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a query regarding rails render method.

If I have something like->

```
hashObj = {"a"=> 1, "b"=>2}
render json: hashObj
```

then I know that render method will internally call JSON.dump(hashObj) to get the json to render.

However I want to use my own custom library (e.g. Oj) to create json, can I do something like this:

```
hashObj = {"a"=> 1, "b"=>2}
render json: Oj.dump(hashObj, mode: :compat)
```

How will render method behave here ? Will it check that we are already passing it a json string and hence it does not need to call JSON.dump now ?

Comment: Why don't you try it out how render behaves?

Comment: I did, but its a bit confusing, hence wanted to clarify it further here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, Rails won't attempt to convert what ever you pass to the `json` option if it's some kind of a string, as you can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb#L112).